# Long text phrases (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I'm wondering what the best practice is for longer text phrases. e.g. in a portfolio program which has longer text section explaining your experience in programming, how is the proper way to handle the following text widget?

`Text('A very long text piece that is way longer that 80 characters, a very long text piece that is way longer that 80 characters, a very long text piece that is way longer that 80 characters, a very long text piece that is way longer that 80 characters')`

I thought about storing it in a JSON file or similar, but that would slow the program, as it would have to convert the JSON file to the object. Also thought about storing the text in a map, such that the 'ugly' code would be hidden away, but yet again it seems a bit lazy and would also obscure the structure a bit, making the code harder to navigate

Comment: I'm confused on what you mean when you say handling the text widget. If you want to hardcode the text do that, or fetch it from a service such as Firebase or a API

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a container with limited width to limit it.
Example,

```
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.8;(//80% of screen.

    return new Container (
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      width: width,
      child: new Column (
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text ("Long text......................", textAlign: TextAlign.left),
         
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear what I'm asking for. It''s not the wrapping in the program, but in the code, as it is one long string which breaks the rule of 80 characters (hope this helps)

Comment: Okay..to me more specific, you want the user to enter a string..of  80 or more characters?

Comment: Not really, it's more that I have long text sections in my program, that will consist of one string inside a Text widget, but this makes that text widget very long in the editor, which made me wonder if there were a more 'clean' or practical way of doing this

Comment: Umm..if you're worried about the text being so long in the editor..try hitting enter when you feel it's getting long...press "enter" within the string..for example,..Text("A lonnnngggggggffgfff<hit enter> texttttttttttttt")

Answer (score 0):

I understand your concern, that you want to write big text inside Text widget without breaking 80 character lint rule.

You can write this way, I hope this is what you expected.

Text('''
A very long text piece that is way longer that 80characters, a very long text
piece that is way longer that 80 characters, a very long text piece that is way
longer that 80 characters, a very long text piece thatis way longer that 80
characters'''),